# Why all core services cannot be registered in core.services.yaml?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

> DrupalKernel
>   Building of Dependency Injection Container and registration of Service Providers Core provides the CoreServiceProvider, which, in addition to registering any core services that cannot be registered in the core.services.yaml file, adds any compiler passes needed by core, e.g. for processing tagged services. Each module can add its own service provider, i.e. a class implementing Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProvider, to register services to the container, or modify existing services.

Why cannot all the core services be registered in core.services.yaml?
 Why do we need a service provider class to register services or modify existing services, when we can register services in module.services.yml?

Comment: For #Q3 when you register the service in module.services.yml you need to point your service to a class. That class is your "Service Provider class". Ex in my_module.services.yml  `class: Drupal\my_module\HelloWorldProvider` and `my_module.hello_world` would be the service in this example.

Comment: Hi @NoSssweat, but we don't use CoreServiceProvider (which implements ServiceProviderInterface) when defining a custom service, isn't it?

Comment: That's just mentioning what Core provides that, but then it goes on to say `Each module can add its own service provider`. Thus, it is not required to use `CoreServiceProvider`.

Comment: So CoreServiceProvider has list of services which is registered and is there a way we can alter that list ? or we can only alter the class defined in the CoreServiceProvider and replace it with our own Custom Class ? @NoSssweat

Comment: Ah no, as it says on [CoreServiceProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21CoreServiceProvider.php/class/CoreServiceProvider/8.2.x) _"This is where Drupal core registers all of its compiler passes. **The service definitions themselves are in core/core.services.yml** with a few, documented exceptions (typically, install requirements)."_

Comment: okay so here comes my other question What does compiler passes mean? @NoSssweat

Comment: That would be offtopic here, you can find the answer to that [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ACYBGNRaHFxx5aw41sl7Nz4b-HGYPv8E-Q:1574405582499&q=Multi-pass+compiler&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecSYxi3w8sc9YanYSWtOXmMM5-IKzsgvd80rySypFFLjYoOyZLh4pTj1c_UNzIvMks00GKS4uRBcJUUj0V2Xpp1j4xcMv7r9ZqlhsIMUgxYTB0PTvhWH2Fg4GAUYeBaxCvuW5pRk6hYkFhcrJOfnFmTmpBYBAJ3-HaiBAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiloOjrnf3lAhXrFjQIHXW9D6MQ6RMwHHoECAwQBA&biw=1280&bih=642)

Comment: @NoSssweat Actually, _compiler passes_ there is a Symfony thing. (See https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html, for example.)

Comment: Actually, a better description is given in [Container Building Workflow](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/dependency_injection/workflow.html), although it still requires to know Symfony's details.

Answer (score 1):

> Why cannot all the core services be registered in core.services.yaml?
>
> Why do we need a service provider class to register services or modify existing services, when we can register services in module.services.yml?

I think the answer to both these questions is that likely some of the services are dynamic. Yaml files can only be used for static registration of services.